# Как сбилдить проект на node.js чтоб на выходе был нативный js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Сделал небольшой тестовый проект на electron (использует node.js) под windows, захотел его заврапить с помощью cordova в apk файл, чтоб можно было открыть с андроида. Но кордова при билде ругается на require (использую пару модулей). Есть ли какие-то готовые решения, или информация по данной проблеме?

Comment: Browserify? Упакует модули в self-invoking functions.

Comment: @other спасибо, немножко почитал, вроде оно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [Browserify](http://browserify.org).
Очень полезный инструмент, позволяет упаковать все используемые модули в функции.
Хабр [о этом инструменте](https://habrahabr.ru/post/224825/).